# Install Wordpress Multisite on MAMP 3.5

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I have followed every tutorial and I still don't have a solution for setting up a wordpress multisite on MAMP 3.5 that points to subdomains. If anyone has any success I would be willing to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

1.install WordPress in the normal way. Download WordPress and use the ‘famous 5 minute install’ to install it on your server or local machine.

2.Open your wp-config.php file which you’ll find in the folder where you installed WordPress. Find the line that :

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

3.Immediately above that line, create a new line that reads as follows:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

4.Now save your wp-config.php file.

For more info about config installation & manging site.
Go to:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/

Comment: That "ultimate guide" doesn't even scratch the surface. [This guide](http://wpdreamer.com/2013/08/how-to-setup-a-localhost-wordpress-sub-domain-multisite-environment/) does a better job of laying out everythign you need but is only for 2.1, not 3,5. I've set up my aliases for the URLs but and I declared the port in my vhosts file but my apache server won't start up.

Comment: @user3411192 I think you should fix your Apache problem first